# Windows Services not found after 3 hours about

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, windows-services

I have a windows service, this service every x second or minute, should perform a task. I have write this service, install it on my SO (Windows 7), so it work for three hours about, then the state of service is "Running" but it has ceased to perform the task. I think, the timer is in crash.

This is a code:

```
            public Service1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                if (!System.Diagnostics.EventLog.SourceExists("AutomaticallyRunScript"))
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.EventLog.CreateEventSource(
                        "AutomaticRunScript", "LoggerAutomaticRunScript");
                }
                log.Info("preparazione file di config in corso...");
                //set parameter from config File
                setParameterFromAppConfig();

                 // get today's date at hours:minutes   
                 DateTime tenAM = DateTime.Today.AddHours(hours);
                 tenAM = tenAM.AddMinutes(minutes);
                 int timeToFirstExecution = 0;
                 // if hours:minutes has passed, get tomorrow at hours:minutes     
                 if (DateTime.Now > tenAM)
                     tenAM = tenAM.AddDays(1);//add 1 day of data

                 // calculate the number of milliseconds in hoursFrequency, minutesFrequency, secondsFrequency time.    
                 int timeBetweenCalls = (int)new TimeSpan(hoursFrequency,
                     minutesFrequency, secondsFrequency).TotalMilliseconds;

                 // if hours:minutes has passed, get tomorrow at hours:minutes 
                 //only if the frequency of the run script is every day
                 if (DateTime.Now > tenAM && hoursFrequency == 24)
                 {
                     tenAM = tenAM.AddDays(1);//add 1 day of data
                     // calculate milliseconds until the next hours:minutes   .   
                     timeToFirstExecution = (int)tenAM.Subtract(DateTime.Now).TotalMilliseconds;
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     timeToFirstExecution = (int)DateTime.Now.AddMilliseconds(timeBetweenCalls).Subtract(DateTime.Now).TotalMilliseconds;
                 }

                 // set the method to execute when the timer executes.    
                 TimerCallback methodToExecute = ProcessFile;



  // start the timer.  The timer will execute "ProcessFile" when the number of seconds between now and    
             // the next hours:minutes elapse.  After that, it will execute every 24 hours.    
             System.Threading.Timer timer = new System.Threading.Timer(methodToExecute, null, timeToFirstExecution, timeBetweenCalls);
             // Block the main thread forever.  The timer will continue to execute.    
             //Thread.Sleep(Timeout.Infinite);
        }

protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
   //
}

protected override void OnStop(string[] args)
{
   //
}

        public void ProcessFile(object obj)
        {
            try
            {
                // do your processing here. 
                String percorsoFiles = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["NameFileBat"];
                string[] percorsoFile = percorsoFiles.Split(';');
                foreach (string filebatch in percorsoFile)
                {
                    //log.Info(": EXECUTE BATCH FILE " + filebatch + " NOW");
                    EventLog.WriteEntry("EXECUTE BATCH FILE " + filebatch + " NOW", EventLogEntryType.Information);
                    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(filebatch);
                    //System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(elapsedTimeBetween2BatchFile);
                }
                EventLog.WriteEntry("***FINISHED***", EventLogEntryType.Information);
                //log.Info("***FINISHED***");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                EventLog.WriteEntry("error, see log file ", EventLogEntryType.Error);
                log.Error("errore: " + e);
            }
        }
```

I have see the log file and there isn't an error log

Comment: Don't put all your initialisation stuff in the constructor, put it in another method an cll that method from the `OnStart` event. It is likely that your timer is getting garbage collected, make it a field rather than a local variable.

Comment: I don't understand. For you how I can fix it?

Comment: Show us how you implemented `OnStart` and `OnStop` and possibly also part of the timer's event handler.

Comment: I have edit my previous post, the I have insert another three method.

Comment: Wow. How do you start/stop the service if there's absolutely no code in `OnStart` and `OnStop`?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, where do I start...

First of all, put as little code as possible into the constructor. All code required to initialize the service should be in `OnStart`, all code required to stop the service (i.e. code to stop the timer) should be in `OnStop`. That's the first thing.

Then it is good practice to stop a timer while the timer event is executing and to restart it in a `finally` block at the end of the timer event.

Third I recommend not to use `System.Threading.Timer` but `System.Timers.Timer` which is easier to handle and allows for "one shot" timers, which *force* you to restart the timer in code. Less things can go wrong here.

Also, do never *ever* create timers as local variables! They may get garbage collected any time after the method is out of focus.

And why is everybody using `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings` when it is so much easier and less error-prone to write `Properties.Settings.Default.NameFileBat`?

---

Short example of how to use `System.Timers.Timer` in service:

```
private System.Timers.Timer myTimer;

protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    myTimer = new Timer(5000);          // Every 5 seconds
    myTimer.AutoReset = false;          // Only 1 event!!
    myTimer.Elapsed += TimerElapsed;    // Event handler
    myTimer.Start();                    // Start the timer
}

protected override void OnStop()
{
    myTimer.Stop();
    myTimer = null;
}

privated void TimerElapsed(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        // Do stuff
    }
    finally
    {
        // Restart if timer variable is not null
        if (myTimer != null)        
            myTimer.Start();
    }
}
```

Comment: I have changed my code. I have insert System.Timers.Timer about of Threading.Timers, and I have change a code int ProcessFile method. Now it's OK?

Comment: It is not a good idea to change the code in the question that's meant to demonstrate the problem to code that doesn't have a problem anymore. Nobody will be able to understand your question anymore. No, your code is not yet ok. First of all `Timer.Enabled = true` and `Timer.Start()` do the same thing. You can omit one of them in `OnStart`. Secondly your timer will not be restarted in case of an exception. Thirdly, `OnStop` does not stop the timer at all. I'll edit my answer to give you a short example.

Comment: I have see you change... but I have a question, in TimerElapsed method, you insert into "finally" myTimer.Start();
but when you execute the method, you should not use mTimer.Stop() or other for stop the timers????

Comment: No, because the `AutoReset` property controls whether the timer runs only once (`false`) or frequently (`true`). I've configured the timer to fire only once, which means that I do not have to stop it, but only start it if I want another event.